# How to call the MongoDB function from NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-connection

I have created a function in the mongodb using the following command : -

```
db.system.js.save({
    _id: "sp_GetCustomerInfo",
    value: function(){
        return db.customer.find()
    }
})
```

I am using **Mongoose Library** in the nodeJS side to perform the operations of mongodb.
Now, I want to call this function from NodeJS side. How can I call this?

Please Help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like code snippet below. Nevertheless this is not a good approach to query for data from a mongoDB. A best practice would be to just use `find()` method from mongoose directly.

```
const conn = mongoose.connect(PATH_TO_DB, err => {
    mongoose.connection.db.eval('sp_GetCustomerInfo()', (err, result) => {
         result;
    })
});
```

Comment: Hi Fabian, my actual implementation doesn't consider only this find() method, actually it has a lot of complex logic. I am basically migrating the MySQL stored procedure to the MongoDB function and now want to call this function from NodeJS.

Comment: And the solution which you have provided is not working for me giving 
(node:27364) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: mongoose.connection.db.eval is not a function error